# How to set filename placeholder while file is being loaded in FilePond?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm using `react-filepond` and I want to display a custom placeholder value where the file name is displayed, while the file is being fetched from the server.

I'm fetching this file using custom logic via load function inside server configuration.

With the configuration provided bellow I'm seeing such output:

[image]

Is there a way to change "undefined" to something else or remove it entirely?

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState([
    {
      options: {
        type: 'local',
      },
    },
  ] as any[]);

const loadFile = (
    source: any,
    load: (file: ActualFileObject | Blob) => void,
    error: (errorText: string) => void,
    progress: any,
    abort: () => void,
  ) => {
    api.downloadFile(
      .then((file) => {
        load(file);
      })
      .catch((e) => error(e));

    // Should expose an abort method so the request can be cancelled
    return {
      abort: () => abort(),
    };
  };
```

Here's the usage of `<FilePond>`

```js
<FilePond
    files={files}
    onupdatefiles={setFiles}
    maxFiles={1}
    acceptedFileTypes={[
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    ]}
    // using custom server functions because our httpClient has required authentication mechanism
    server={{
        load: loadFile,
    }}
/>
```

I've tried setting file name in the initial files array, but by doing that my custom `loadFile` function is not being called anymore:

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState([
    {
      options: {
        // this will trigger FilePond load function
        type: 'local',
        file: {
            name: 'test',
        },
      },
    },
  ] as any[]);
```

[image]